# Terraform: Is there any way to group targets (resources) for apply/destroy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

What better way to group resources in terraform?

For example I have two S3 buckets:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "name1" {
  provider = aws.provider
  bucket = "name1"
  acl    = "private"

  force_destroy = true

  versioning {
    enabled = false
  }
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "name2" {
  provider = aws.provider
  bucket = "name2"
  acl    = "private"

  force_destroy = true

  versioning {
    enabled = false
  }
}
```

What better way to group these two buckets?

Something like:

```
resource "some_terraform_resource_group" "group_name" {
  ? depends_on = ... ?
  resources_in_group = [
   aws_s3_bucket.name1,
   aws_s3_bucket.name2
  ]
  provider = aws.provider
  some_others options = ...
}
```

And will be able to run:

```
terraform apply -target=some_terraform_resource_group.group_name
terraform destroy -target=some_terraform_resource_group.group_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special group resource in terraform as in your example, but you for what you described, a regular [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) could be used.

For example:

```
variable "bucket_names" {
   default = ["name1", "name2"]
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "name" {
 
  for_each = toset(var.bucket_names)

  provider = aws.provider
  bucket = each.value
  acl    = "private"

  force_destroy = true

  versioning {
    enabled = false
  }
}
```

Then, the resulting `aws_s3_bucket.name` will behave like a group containing two resources for your buckets.

#### Update based on comments

To "group" resources of different types, you can use terraform [modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Of course it was just a simple case in my example. Actually I want to grouping couple different resources. Now I'm using `depends_on` parameter. For example I have VPC + EC2 + LoadBalancer. LoadBalancer is depending on VPC and EC2. So I can run apply with `LoadBalancer` target, and VPC + EC2 will be created automatically. But when I want to destroy resources I need to run destroy with VPC target (if EC2 depends on VPC and LB depends on EC2). That is pretty hard to remember and works good only if I want to destroy whole VPC with all depending targets.

Comment: @rzlvmp There are no groups, except terraform modules. So you can group different resoruces as modules.

Comment: Hmmm... looks like modules little bit complicated than just grouping feature. But if there is no another way, I will try to check it. Thank you.

Comment: @rzlvmp No problem. I will update the answer with modules link.